# Mod rewrite works for one site, but not the other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mod rewrite which looks like this:

```
rewriteRule ^info/([0-9]+).html$ info.php?n=$1
```

This works:
`mydomain1.com/info/8.html` to `mydomain1.com/info.php?n=8`

on one domain, but not the other:

`mydomain2.com/info/8.html`

The domains is on the same server, the only difference is that mydomain2.com is hosted as an addon domain in a folder below mydomain1.com

What could be the reason that it works for one domain but not the other?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: The only one I get is 404, and I can't see any in the "error.log". Is there any log that I have overlooked (on a shared server at hostgator (linux)?

Comment: Doesn't the 404-page contain a path?